# How to read source file path from text file in informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a flat file and its path is stored inside text file i want to read that path from text file and use it inside session task to execute the session
[image]

and i want to read this file and take that path and use it in source path
[image]

so how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can do is, create a parameter file

```
test.prm
[folder.Session name]
$PMSourceFileName=C:\myfolder\myfile.txt
```

Mention $PMSourceFileName in session Sourcefilename tab.

Then use this file as parameter file in workflow. Make sure session name and folder name are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use two sessions in your workflow.

1. use the first one to read the file content and set assign the content to the variable
2. pass the session1 variable to the workflow
3. use workflow variable in the session2 as the surce file name